# IncompatibleClassChangeError: Phoenix JDBC connectivity

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to connect to HBase using Phoenix JDBC Driver and getting below error:
This is simple implementation of JDBC connection manager.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClusterIdProtos$ClusterId$Builder does not implement the requested interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.mergeFrom(ProtobufUtil.java:3154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:879)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:635)
```

Based on my research it seems, I need to use some shaded package of phoenix-client. I am not able to figure it out.

Details:
Phoenix version: 4.9.0-HBase-1.1
HBase Version: 1.1.2

Comment: have you seen [PHOENIX-3025](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-3025)